# Haskell and Regex with Intersections

Tags: regex, haskell, pcre

I am using regex with Haskell along with Text.Regex.PCRE and in my case I have:

```
Prelude Text.Regex.PCRE> getAllTextMatches ("32UMU1078" =~ "(\\d{1,2})([C-X&&[^IO]])([A-Z&&[^IO]])([A-Z&&[^IO]])(\\d{2,10})" :: AllTextMatches [] String)
[]
```

I am expecting some values returned but list is empty. However this returns what is expected:

```
Prelude Text.Regex.PCRE> getAllTextMatches ("32UMU1078" =~ "(\\d{1,2})([C-X])([A-Z])([A-Z])(\\d{2,10})" :: AllTextMatches [] String)
["32UMU1078"]
```

So if I remove the intersections like `&&[^IO]` there are no problems.
As I just discovered PCRE doesn't support intersections. Any alternative library with Haskell that support it?

Comment: No. PCRE doesn't support any kind of character class operations like intersections.

Comment: In some places I read it. Bad sources :) However I changed a bit the question. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCRE does not support character class intersection/subtraction.

However, you may work around it with negative lookaheads and other methods.

Here, replace `"(\\d{1,2})([C-X&&[^IO]])([A-Z&&[^IO]])([A-Z&&[^IO]])(\\d{2,10})"` with

```
"(\\d{1,2})((?![IO])[C-X])((?![IO])[A-Z])((?![IO])[A-Z])(\\d{2,10})"
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That is, replace the subtractions with lookaheads, `[C-X&&[^IO]]` -> `(?![IO])[C-X]`.

Another way, that is more verbose, is to spell out the character classes:

```
"(\\d{1,2})([C-HJ-NP-X])([A-HJ-NP-Z])([A-HJ-NP-Z])(\\d{2,10})"
```

So, `[C-X]` that does not match `I` and `O` must be written as `[C-HJ-NP-X]`.